TypeORM entities are not found in the test file
I'm using TypeORM and ExpressJS. I'm encountering an issue while attempting to access the database in a test file. Whenever I encounter an error, it says that the entities is not found.
Here's my index.ts file:
import './config';

import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';

import initRoutes from './routes';

import { AppDataSource } from './utils/data-source';
import CreateUser from './seeder/createUser';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.APP_PORT;

let server: any;

const startServer = () => {
  server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App starting at PORT ${PORT}`);
  });
};

const setupMiddlewares = () => {
  // CORS middleware
  app.use(cors());

  // Enable logger (morgan)
  app.use(morgan('[:date[clf]] :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'));

  // Request body parsing middleware
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
};

const startDatabase = async () => {
  try {
    await AppDataSource.initialize();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error while connecting the database', error);
    process.exit(0);
  }
};

const startApp = async () => {
  // Start Database
  await startDatabase();

  // Add Default user in database
  await CreateUser();

  // Start Server
  startServer();

  // Setup Global middleware
  setupMiddlewares();

  // Initialize routes
  initRoutes(app);

  // Export the app instance after everything is set up
  return app;
};

const closeApp = async () => {
  try {
    // Close the server
    await server.close();

    // Destroy the AppDataSource
    await AppDataSource.destroy();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error closing app:', error);
  }
};

startApp();

export { startApp, closeApp };


And here's my test file:
import request from "supertest";
import { startApp, closeApp } from "../src/index";

describe('Todo API', () => {
  let app;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    app = await startApp();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await closeApp();
  });

  it('healthcheck', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .get('/healthcheck')

    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
  });
});


And here's the error I'm receiving:
Error Image
You can see in this error EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found. since we are creating a default user inside the startApp function.
Note: My app is working fine, but I only encounter issues when I run my test cases. I don't know why, but somehow my TypeORM is not properly making a connection with my database.
I expect to run test cases for my API.
